# PyTesseract causes PIL to raise ValueError: tile cannot extend outside image

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, valueerror, python-tesseract

I'm working on a program that splits a picture into a bunch of different parts, then converts each part to a string using pytesseract. The problem is that PIL, which is used in Pytesseract, keeps raising ValueError: tile cannot extend outside image. I don't understand why this is happening, because I'm not using PIL to crop the image. Why is it raising that error and how do I fix it?

```
 import pytesseract
 import cv2
 original = cv2.imread('image path')
 newImg = original[topBound:bottombound, leftBound:rightBound]
 txt = pytesseract.image_to_string(newImg)
```

Obviously that isn't all of the code, and the splicing of original image is more complicated, but that is the code that is causing the error, specifically the `pytesseract.image_to_string(newImg)` portion
Edit 1: I forgot to mention that I tried what similar but not the same questions suggested, which was to change how pytesseract imports PIL's Image, but it didn't help.
Edit 2: Changed code as requested. [Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QROwB.jpg)

Solved, It was a problem with my splicing. I made a clamp method and switched the min and max values, so it always returned 0. Therefore, the image had dimensions of 0*0, causing the error

Comment: Please provide a **Minimal Complete Verifiable Example** https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example if you'd like help. It's very difficult, and often a waste of time, trying to guess problems arising from code we can't see. Add at the minimum the `imports` and how you load and slice the images and also a sample image. Thank you.

Comment: Your array indices are reversed, you put the height first, then the width.

Comment: You are right, they are switched, but I tried switching them and got the same result. I will change that in the post.

Comment: Have you converted to greyscale?

Comment: No, but I will try that. How will that help?

Comment: Making sure that none of the dimension of the image is 0 will resolve this issue. Thanks for mentioning the solution.